pip install seems to be working, but when I try to run code I get thrown an error
I'm beginning to work on an AI system from a tutorial I found on youtube, and I'm doing this in VSCode.
However, when I try to install packages like pip install pyttsx3,installing package, everything goes well. But when I then run my code:
my error
Written error:
PS D:\Username> & C:/Users/Usernme/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Username/Python_AI.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Username\Python_AI.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyttsx3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'

Does the fact that I'm running it from 2 different drives make a difference?
I am a fairly beginner in python.
Scanning the web, reading a few different websites, looking around in stackoverflow, I've found nothing that has fixed my issue.

You have installed the package globally using Python 3.12, but are trying to run the code using Python 3.11. What people typically do is create a virtual environment with whichever Python version they require, activate that environment, and install packages and run code from it.
